# React Material UI | Passing Style Props to Components

Tags: reactjs

How to pass style props to a component based on a button click. So, I am having two components one is called Button Component and the other is called Answer Component. I have three buttons in the button component. If we click the first button, it should display the Answer component with BG Color Blue. If I click the second button in the Button Component. It should display the Answer Component with BG Color Red and Vice versa. In what way i can achieve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you make it work with react material-ui?

Comment: Yes @gsalgadotoledo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the style around by using callbacks in the buttons component to signal to a parent component you wish to change the style of the answer component.

We can start by having a parent component that will store the color state. Then we make a callback function to give to the child to enable it to change the our parent's color.  state. For the answer component we simply need to send the parent's color state down to that component for use in changing the BG color.

```js
class ChildAnswer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={`answer ${this.props.color}`}> Answer component </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => { this.props.changeColorCallback('blue'); }}>Change to BLUE</button>
        <button onClick={() => { this.props.changeColorCallback('red'); }}>Change to RED</button>
        <button onClick={() => { this.props.changeColorCallback('green'); }}>Change to GREEN</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          color: 'red'
      };
  }

  changeColorCallback = (newColor) => {
      this.setState({ color: newColor });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildAnswer color={this.state.color} />
        <ChildButtons changeColorCallback={this.changeColorCallback}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
button {
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.answer {
    width: 200px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```